# how do you extract the geolocation information from a photo in android?

Tags: java, android, geolocation, exif

I am fairly new to android and I am creating an app that uses the camera intent to take a photo and stores it into a database along with some other info. my trouble is that I need to get the latitude and longitude from that photo and store it into the database as well. I have searched very thoroughly and can not seem to find out how to extract the location information from a photo. any help will be greatly appreciated.

thanks in advance

Comment: http://www.ohmrefresh.info/2010/09/how-to-get-exif-picture-information-android-2/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[Create an `ExifInterface` from the filename](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/ExifInterface.html#ExifInterface(java.lang.String)) and then you can call [`getLatLong()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/ExifInterface.html#getLatLong(float[])) to get the coordinates.

Comment: @user652393 Glad to help!  To indicate this answer solved your problem, there's a little checkmark thing on the left you can click to accept this as the right answer, which will give us both a few reputation points.